# How to split a string into different lengthed chunks?

Tags: python, string

In order to format the string properly, I was required to split it into different lengths of chunks.

As an example, This is a string - `"25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565"`, For splitting it in fixed length chunks, I would simply use steps and slicing:

```
s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
n = 2
print("-".join([s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]))
```

However, What could I do if `n` was a list of numbers to be split, as example:

```
s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
n = [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]
```

Only solution I made was this:

```
print("-".join([s[0:8], s[8:12], s[12:16], s[16:20], s[20:24], s[24:32]]))
```

Which is not *"pythonic"* and more necessarily not reliable if the length of the string is large.

The output from the last example of code:

```
25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0-4977-50ea1299
```

So can this be done in a more pythonic one liner way? If not, what are other more automatic ways for this to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
>>> n = [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]
>>> print '-'.join([s[sum(n[:i]):sum(n[:i+1])] for i in range(len(n))])
```

Output

```
25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0-4977-50ea12992b30
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Output is - `---19f75e3f`

Comment: Now the output is - `--19f7-5e3`

Comment: @ShellRox A bit late but here's a 1 liner without itertools. Beware it is inefficient because it keeps calling sum. But it works.

Answer (score 5):

Create an iterator from the string and slice incrementally using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
it = iter(s)
n = [8, 4, 4, 12]

s = '-'.join(''.join(islice(it, None, x)) for x in n)
print(s)
# 25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea
```

Note that the trailing part of the string is lost if the total size of the slice(s) does not equal the length of the string; iterator is not completely exhausted.

You may append the trailing part (if needed) in a final preprocessing stage:

```
s += '-' + ''.join(it)
print(s)
# 25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea-12992b30d565
```

---

Here's another approach that uses a for loop, slicing the string incrementally by increasing the start index:

```
start = 0
d = []
for i in n:
   d.append(s[start:start+i])
   start += i
d.append(s[start:])
print('-'.join(d))
# 25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea-12992b30d565
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It cannot be done without the help of the itertools correct?

Comment: @ShellRox Any reason for not wanting to use itertools?

Comment: Kolodoye I'm just trying to avoid extra use of modules, But if there is no alternative simple way then it's not a problem.

Comment: @ShellRox it can. I'm just trying to figure out why my one liner isn't working :p

Comment: @ShellRox itertools is a great package and if you want *pythonic*, you should learn to use it. It's also not a third-party dependency, as Python comes with it by default. Spending a line in your script to import it does not make your code inelegant, or inefficient in any way. Unless this is some kind of homework constraint, in which case you should state so in the question.

Comment: @Reti43 I have used iterators such as permutations and combinations in the past, I'm just trying to avoid modules in this case to write the code in as less lines as possible.

Comment: Also, sorry, but the second example output was not fully correct though.

Comment: @ShellRox How do you mean not fully correct? The indices you provided do not match the length of the string.

Comment: The output is `25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea` but it should be `5c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea-12992b30d565`, I think it's not fully split by dashes?

Comment: @ShellRox Your list `n` has only four indices. You should include an index for the last part!

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It's not possible to get the index automatically right?

Comment: @ShellRox Add `d.append(s[start:])` before the `print`. That'll append the rest of the string. See update!

Comment: Yes, but then last item is not 12 length long- `25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0-4977-50ea12992b30-d565`

Comment: @ShellRox I'm worried that you're asking for too much. If your `n` were `[8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]`, that would give what you've shown but you've given a different `n` in your question, so I don't see what the problem really is.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I'm sorry it was my fault, But the problem still remains same even if n is altered, So there is no actual way this can be done with iterations?

Comment: @ShellRox I think you may want to take a break. I'm not going to comment any further. All the answers here provided do exactly what you've described in your question.

Comment: @ShellRox I honestly think you should select this answer. It is clear, concise, very pythonic, and does exactly what your examples have dictated. If not, you should be more clear when explaining your problem to prevent wasting both yours and our time.

Comment: @Coldspeed How can i select the answer if it doesn't give the output it is supposed to? I'm looking for pythonic way to do same thing as `print("-".join([s[0:8], s[8:12], s[12:16], s[16:20], s[20:24], s[24:32]]))` currently does, But i can't seem to find the proper answer which works in all versions of python.

Comment: @ShellRox This answer and the answer you just accepted give the same output. My answer also gives the same output, and it's a one liner. Did you check it out?

Comment: @Coldspeed Your answer gives the output of `25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0497750ea`, But accepted answer gives the output of `['25c319f7', '5e3f', 'bed5', 'a9f0', '4977', '50ea12992b30']` which is correct in this case when i use "-".join() function on it. As you see, your output ends with `ea`, Sean's output fully splits the string.

Comment: @ShellRox Omg... I was using the `n = [8, 4, 4, 12]` from your example in your QUESTION. If you use `n = [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]` it'll give the same answer. Like I said, be clear with your questions, and you'll get clear answers.

Comment: @Coldspeed Thank YOU, you just proved two facts with the answer 1. One liner solution is possible for the answer. 2. I was an idiot.

Comment: @ShellRox Yeah. I've edited your question for consistency. Like I said, do be clear with your questions and you'll save everyone a lot of headache. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-linear I'm afraid, but from the top of my head:

```
s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
n = [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]
res=[]
for split in n:
    temp=s[:split]
    s=s[split:]
    res.append(temp) 
print(res)
```

The output is an array with the respective strings that can be manipulated accordingly:

```
 ['25c319f7', '5e3f', 'bed5', 'a9f0', '4977', '50ea12992b30']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
n = [8, 4, 4, 12]

def make_chunks(s,n):
    result = []
    for length in n:
        result.append(s[:length])
        s = s[length:]
    if s:
        result.append(s)
    return '-'.join(result)

print(make_chunks(s,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we start from the listed data:

```
string = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
lengths = [8, 4, 4, 12]
```

We can use a scan to find the beginnings or ends of each part:

```
import itertools
ends = list(itertools.accumulate(lengths))
```

It appears `accumulate` is specific to Python 3, so we might need a workaround to do the scan in Python 2 (this one's slow at O(n²)):

```
starts = [sum(lengths[:i]) for i in range(len(lengths))]
```

And then we can use the combination to extract parts:

```
dashed = '-'.join(string[end-length : end]
                  for end,length in zip(ends,lengths))
```

The advantage of all this length/index manipulation is that it doesn't create copies of the string, only its individual parts. Otherwise Sean's solution is very neat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Definitely useful but i'm trying to find solution which uses regular python only.

Comment: How is this not regular Python? It's all standard library.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I mean i'm trying to avoid using modules in this case since it is possible.

Comment: It is always possible, but whether it's efficient or legible is another matter. An example of doing it without the itertools module is the Python 2 comprehension I showed.

Comment: I am required to use the ends array which uses itertools accumulate which is Python 3 specific, Is there any alternative for python2?

Comment: I already wrote a Python 2 alternative, named `starts` above.

Comment: Sorry for late response, But then how could i extract parts from the string without end variable?

Comment: Please think a little. What is `end-length`?

Comment: I'm not talking about `end-length`, I'm talking about `ends` array which is generated from `itertools.accumulate`.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of possible characters is known and the size of each chunk is fixed, it can also be done with regex and [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group):

```py
import re

s = '25c319f75e3fbed5a9f0497750ea12992b30d565'
n = [8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12]

pattern = ''
for nchars in n:
    pattern += f'([\w]{{{nchars}}})'
print(pattern)
# '([\\w]{8})([\\w]{4})([\\w]{4})([\\w]{4})([\\w]{4})([\\w]{12})'

pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.ASCII)
matches = pattern.search(s)

print(matches.groups())
# ('25c319f7', '5e3f', 'bed5', 'a9f0', '4977', '50ea12992b30')

print("-".join(matches.groups()))
# '25c319f7-5e3f-bed5-a9f0-4977-50ea12992b30'
```

The regex pattern is basically a repeating pattern of:

```
([\\w]{n})
```

for each `n` item from the list of chunk sizes, where:

- [`(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) means "*Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string*"
- [`\w`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) means "*Matches characters considered alphanumeric in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].*" (assuming a `re.ASCII` flag)
- [`{n}`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) means "*Specifies that exactly `n` copies of the previous RE should be matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example, `a{6}` will match exactly six 'a' characters, but not five.*"