# How to add hyphens to numbers in a dataframe column? python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I'm trying to format a dataframe column by adding hyphens to make it easier to read.  My dataframe looks like this:

```
            Parcel No.
Property A  0622280070620
Property B  123456789345
Property C  123450694568
```

my desired outcome is:

```
            Parcel No.
Property A  06-2228-007-0620
Property B  12-3456-789-3452
Property C  13-3450-694-3568
```

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split the string into different lengths chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648145/split-the-string-into-different-lengths-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers always have exactly 13 digits:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Parcel No.": [1111111111111, 2222222222222, 3333333333333]},
                  index=["Property A", "Property B", "Property C"])

df["Parcel No."] = df["Parcel No."].astype(str).apply(lambda num: f"{num[:2]}-{num[2:6]}-{num[6:9]}-{num[9:]}")

print(df)
>                   Parcel No.
  Property A  11-1111-111-1111
  Property B  22-2222-222-2222
  Property C  33-3333-333-3333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str.replace` if your number length is fixed

```py
df['hypen'] = (df['Parcel No.'].astype(str)
               .str.replace(r'(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})', r'\1-\2-\3-\4', regex=True))
```